# Angular $compile has a delay

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a case where I use $compile to add some directive to the html from code.
My problem is that you can actually see the delay of building the html.
My container is a div and I can see how it is small in the beginning and only after a short delay the div is filled with the compiled html.

This is how I do it:

```
var content = "some template";
$(container).html(content);
$compile($('#someElementInTheContainer', container))(scope);
```

When I don't use directives but plain text and jquery I don't see the delay.

Couldn't find a way to solve it, any suggestions?

Comment: will be some delay if template is on server still . Show more directive code

Comment: Try read this post - I think it will helpful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599896/long-compile-duration-understanding-the-nature-of-the-delay-in-angularjs